# How to request https endpoints through quarkus

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, https, quarkus

I am creating endpoint that is dependent on another endpoint,i have created interface and did all of that stuff but when i requested https://example.com to give me info it did not responded and request timeout exception came up.the quarkus is not supporting https request i also have added certificates kindly let me know what i am doing wrong or what i need to do.

```
  quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.file=META-INF/dev.crt
    quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-file=META-INF/dev.com.key
    com.package.xyz/mp-rest/url=https://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify some properties in your application.properties file:

```
quarkus.http.ssl-port=8443
quarkus.http.insecure-requests=enabled
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=keystore.jks
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-password=password
```

Documentation source I used for this was the Quarkus cookbook available from RedHat:  https://developers.redhat.com/books/quarkus-cookbook  see section 3.8